# Reference data in SQLDataReader by column and rows or any alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, sqldatareader

I am running a stored procedure and the result is this format

```
+------+--------+-----+-------+
|  ID  | Resign | Sum | Count |
+------+--------+-----+-------+
| 1234 |      0 | 400 |     3 |
| 1234 |      1 | 800 |     4 |
+------+--------+-----+-------+
```

I tried this code to reference the values returned by the query but, it seem not working the way I want it

```
if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand();
    sc.CommandText = "usp_GetResignPool";
    sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sc.Connection = conn;
    sc.Parameters.Add(AddParam(EndDate, "@EndDate"));
    sc.Parameters.Add(AddParam(am_id, "@id"));

    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = sc.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
            {
                if reader. // lost here
            }
```

### **How can I do something like this. ↓**

```
int resigned = 0, resign_count = 0, not_resigned = 0, notresign_count =0;

if (read["Resigned"] == 1)
{
    resigned = read["sum"];
    resign_count = read["count"];
}
else
{
    not_resigned = read["sum"];
    notresign_count = read["count"]; 
}
```

It is not important that I used SQLDataReader.

Edit: Real column names

```
ID        Resigned    sum                    count
--------- ----------- ---------------------- -----------
```

Comment: Please post your stored procedure code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
int resign = 0;
int not_resign = 0;
int resign_count = 0;
int not_resign_count = 0;

while (reader.Read())
{   
    if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["Resigned"]) == 1)
    {
        resign = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Sum"]);        
        resign_count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Count"]);        
    }
    else
    {
        not_resign = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Sum"]);        
        not_resign_count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Count"]);        
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It didn't work because you don't have a column in your table named `"Resigned"`, like you have when you are working with your `SqlDataReader`.

**EDIT**: I think the root of the problem is the way you are adding parameters.  `AddParam()` is not the method you want to be using.  Therefore, your result set is probably empty.

```
....

SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(); 
sc.CommandText = "usp_GetResignPool"; 
sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
sc.Connection = conn; 
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate);
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", am_id);

SqlDataReader reader; 
reader = sc.ExecuteReader(); 

using (reader = sc.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(read["Resign"]) == 1)   
        {   
            resigned = Convert.ToInt32(read["Sum"]);   
            resign_count = Convert.ToInt32(read["Count"]);   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            not_resigned = Convert.ToInt32(read["Sum"]);   
            notresign_count = Convert.ToInt32(read["Count"]);    
        } 
    }
}
```

Notice how I changed your element indicator to `"Resign"`.  This needs to match the column that is returned in your dataset.  Or, you could use a column number to get this, like so:

```
        if (Convert.ToInt32(read[1]) == 1)   
        {   
            resigned = Convert.ToInt32(read[2]);   
            resign_count = read[3];   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            not_resigned = Convert.ToInt32(read[2]);   
            notresign_count = Convert.ToInt32(read[3]);    
        }
```

***Also, keep in my that in every iteration or your `while` loop, you'll be overwriting the variables `resigned`, `resign_count` or `not_resigned` and `notresign_count`.***

Comment: `Error 6 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'` I might need casting?

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter Check out my edit.  Change the way you add parameters.

Comment: Yes. You need to use: reader.GetInt() method to retrieve the value.

Comment: +1 for the code and help. Only Convert.Into32() is missing. Needs to be with all references. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your query from the procedure?
Are the column names really "Sum" and "Count"?
There are reserved words, maybe you should try using "AS" and give other names to these to columns in the projection.

Comment: yes the column names are the same. I can change it. My last code is actually psuedo code. I am not sure if it will work.